# xcodebuild - change the name of xctestrun output file name

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, xcodebuild

I am using a distributed CI where one agent outputs the `xctestrun` package, so that a different build agent can pick it up and run the tests without building the app again.

We are running into issues where the name of the `xctestrun` packages are not same because of the SDK it was built with. Is there a way to specify the name of the `xctestrun` package in the `xcodebuild` command?

Comment: Some searching on the internet showed that `xcodebuild` has an `-xctestrun` parameter that may be useful for this? See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html

Comment: That is only to specify the name of the xctestrun file when you want to run the xctestrun package.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Jaroslav IIRC, we just used some regex logic/globbing to pick up the package.. not ideal, but it worked well before we switched to a cloud CI system.